# How to check if Record exists

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to able to check if a record exists in the DB with a specific 'ID' and create one if it does not have one( i.e, Doesnt exist) Like so...
I would also like to fetch "Num" For a specific record after it has been updated.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

db = lite.connect("test.db")
id_to_be_added = "123456789101112"

db.execute("CREATE TABLE USERS (ID TEXT, NUM INT)")

Query = "{ SOMETHING IN SQL }"  # This returns either True or False
if Query:
    db.execute("UPDATE USERS SET NUM = NUM + 1 WHERE ID =  {};".format(id_to_be_added))

else:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO USERS ({}, 0)".format(id_to_be_added))

num_to_be_printed = db.execute("SELECT NUM FROM USERS WHERE ID = {}".format(id_to_be_added))

print("{0} has {1}").format(id_to_be_added, num_to_be_printed)
```

Comment: Must your query return true or false? Is it ok to return 0 (i.e. no record exists) or something >0 (i.e. at least one record does exist)?

Comment: Yup, Just has to return some indication that a record exists.

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)...

Answer (score 0):

Either create a primary key and use `INSERT OR REPLACE` query, or use a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using cur.fetchall()

```
import sqlite3 as lite

db = lite.connect(r"test.db")
id_tba = r"123456789101112"
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = {}".format(id_tba))

if len(cur.fetchall()) > 0:
    db.execute("UPDATE USERS SET NUM = NUM + 1 WHERE ID =  {};".format(id_tba))
else:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO USERS ({}, 0)".format(id_tba))

num_to_be_printed = db.execute("SELECT NUM FROM USERS WHERE ID = {}".format(id_tba))
print("{0} has {1}").format(id_tba, num_to_be_printed)
```